# FindBugs plugin does not work on projects imported from GitHub

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I have always used FindBugs, and it is really useful in many cases. But I couldn't get to find why it does not work on projects imported from GitHub. Projects imported into Eclipse using Git as the source does not have an option to run FindBugs.

Does anyone know why, and a solution to this? I do love to use git extensions on Eclipse, as well as FindBugs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the project that you imported from Git recognised as a Java project (i.e. it has a `J` under the project folder icon)? If not then FindBugs won't be enabled for the project. If that's the case the remote repository almost certainly hasn't added the `.project` and `.classpath` files which are what Eclipse uses to determine if it's a Java project or not.

You should be able to convert it to a Java project by right-clicking and doing 'Configure -> Convert to Java Project'. If that doesn't work, delete the project (but without deleting the files) and then create a File -> New Java project in the same location.

Comment: I understand, but still it does not work... The project is a maven project, and whatever I do, I cannot get to run FindBugs on it. I tried what you recommended to do before but the only thing happens is that it gets converted into a maven project, without any option to run FindBugs again.

Comment: If the Maven project you are working on is a parent pom (i.e. <packaging>pom</packaging> then this is a non-Java project. Chances are there are sub-maven modules underneath that you need to import as separate Java projects which you can then run FindBugs on.